# Formula for weight supported by a magnet with ferrofluid

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics

While playing around with some cylindrical neodymium magnets and ferrofluid, I noticed how adding ferrofluid to one side of the magnet causes it to glide over smooth surfaces in a virtually frictionless manner due to the layer of ferrofluid separating the underside of the magnet from the surface.

Consider a cylindrical, axially polarized permanent magnet of mass $m$, radius $r$, length $l$, and pull force $F$. Suppose the magnet is immersed in ferrofluid and removed along with any ferrofluid it holds on to, then placed on a flat, smooth, rigid surface. **What is the largest value of** $m$ **at which an appreciable (i.e. enough to slide easily) layer of ferrofluid separates the magnet from the surface?**

My intuition is that this is going to involve concepts from fluid mechanics, of which I have little knowledge. Perhaps the magnet increases the surface tension of the ferrofluid?

I am not sure what physical parameters are relevant for the ferrofluid. Assume it is the ferrofluid described in this [material safety datasheet](https://ferrofluid.ferrotec.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/efhsds.pdf). Please make any simplifying assumptions or approximations necessary to provide a rough estimate. I will also accept an answer pointing to experimental measurements with a setup similar to what I have described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you determine the effective coefficient of friction, including its dependency on pressure, speed, etc., you'll be able to calculate everything else.

One possible method is to build a platform (a rigid plate made out of plastic, plywood or non ferrous metal) with three or four identical cylindrical magnets glued to the bottom.

If the magnets are dipped into ferrofluid, the platform could be moved around on a flat surface.

[image]

Now you can put various weights on the platform and see how much horizontal force you need to get it to move (maximum static friction) and to keep it moving at various speeds (dynamic friction).

You can use a dynamometer or just a string-pulley-weight setup.

The only formula you'll need to use is $f=\mu N$.